# how to restart gstreamer pipeline that is streaming over udp if network connection breaks

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

I am running a gstreamer pipeline in a jetson xavier NX and streaming a 4k live stream over udp to a server. I am running a shell script which runs the pipeline directly using CLI. When the connection breaks and the stream cuts, the pipeline says 'network is unreachable`. However as the network resets itself soon and i want the pipeline to restart. How can i find out if the pipeline has stopped and restart it? The pipeline stops but the process continues running and it does not restart on its own. I want to restart the process if the pipeline breaks.

Comment: You should start writing your own application when you want to control specific behavior. That is not what `gst-launch-1.0` is for.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch　Can you give me an example link?

Comment: For what exactly? https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/helloworld.html?gi-language=c? There is a lot of documentation. There won't be a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following for sender: Here using videotestsrc at low resolution, rescaling with HW into 4K in NVMM memory for H264 encoding and RTP/UDP multicast streaming :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ev videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=NV12,width=3840,height=2160' ! nvv4l2h264enc insert-sps-pps=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! udpsink port=5000 host=224.1.1.1
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ev udpsrc port=5000 multicast-group=224.1.1.1  ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=500 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! fpsdisplaysink text-overlay=0 video-sink=xvimagesink
```

It may take a few seconds to connect and display after starting or restarting, but seems restarting fine after network connection stopped and then again available, but this was only tested on a single AGX Xavier being both sender and receiver and using Network manager to disconnect/reconnect. Other cases over networks may be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to write your own application instead of using gst-launch as already suggested. The learning curve for this is pretty steep so the alternative is to monitor the stderr output and parse the messages to find "network is unreachable" information, kill the the old process and relaunch gst-launch.